# Trigonometry unequal bisector region, find intersection

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

I am kinda confused and would appreciate help. I have two lines intersecting. Angle `a` is known and as well `b` and `c`.  I am looking for `P1` and `P2`

I am not sure what to search for online, I found bisect, but this is only if `b` and `c` would be equal length and even then I am not sure if this will help me.

Any Ideas from the big minds?
[image]

Comment: Hmm, from the figure, $P1$ and $P2$ are points. Do you want the *distances* of $P1$ and $P2$ from the point of intersection of the two lines?

Comment: Hint: let $O$ be the intersection of the two lines, $P$ the intersection of the segments of length $b,c$, and $\theta=\angle POP_1\,$. Then solve the system $PO \sin(\theta) = b\,$, $PO \sin(\alpha - \theta) = c\,$ for $PO\,$ and $\theta\,$.

Comment: @N.Bach Jep, i want to have the distance between the intersection point on P1/P2.

Comment: @dxiv I am a little confused with the Naming of the variables. Where are P0 and P1 located? Appreciate your help!

Comment: @user1767754 $P_1$ is the point marked `P1` on your figure, $O$ is the vertex of angle $\alpha$, and $P$ is the point of intersection of the perpendiculars drawn at $P_1$ and $P_2$ to the respective lines.

Comment: @dxiv I've updated the image...but I am not sure...What is P0, is it the intersection between the segment b and c? But that we denoted already as P. ∠POP1 : is this the angle between P and P1? Do you mind drawing a sketch? That would help a lot– user1767754 56 mins ago

Comment: "$PO$" is the distance between point $P$ and point $O$. It's the capital letter "o", not the digit. This kind of confusion is precisely why I prefer the subscript notation "$P_i$" over "$Pi$".
As for the angle, it's the angle between line segments $OP$ (again between $O$ and $P$) and $OP_1$.